# Accidentally created an infinite while loop in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I've recently been learning C# for my A-Level programming project where I am creating a game. I have a sprite which I can move about the screen but I would like the sprite to only be able to move 6 times before it's forced to stop moving. I thought that I could do this by having a variable that would decrement every time that the sprite was moved (using the keyboard). However, I have somehow created an infinite loop which I did not want. I discovered this with the Console.WriteLine(spaceMoved); which will not be in my final code. I've tried all sorts of things but I can't get rid of this infinite loop. I am creating this in a Windows Forms Application by the way.

```
private void Gameplay_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int spaceMoved = 6;

        do
        {
            int x = placeholder1.Location.X;
            int y = placeholder1.Location.Y;

            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 64;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 64;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 64;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 64;

            placeholder1.Location = new Point(x, y);

            spaceMoved--;

            Console.WriteLine(spaceMoved);

        } while (spaceMoved > 0);
```

Comment: you need to declare spaceMoved outside of this method, otherwise it is reinstantiated every time

Comment: I doubt this is an infinite loop. I don't see how that would be possible with this code. It seems more likely that this function is called once per tick while the key is down, so `spaceMoved` gets reset everytime the function runs. How are you pressing the key?

Comment: This code will iterate just 6 times, it's not an infinite loop. Did you mean to limit the number of *events* perhaps, so holding a cursor button down won't result in 1000 steps?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to throttle the KeyDown event perhaps, and only allow one move every 1/6 s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an infinite loop. Your `do while` will execute 6 times.

However, you seem to have glossed over the fact that this will execute 6 times **whenever `Gameplay_KeyDown` is called**. Every time, the counter "resets" (using imprecise language here) so it executes another 6 times.

If you want the counter to be remembered outside of a single function call, you must declare it outside of the function.

This also means you don't need the `do while` inside the function. Every function will perform exactly one move (as long as the player has moves left).

Something along these lines:

```
private int movesLeft = 6;

private void Gameplay_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(movesLeft > 0)
    {
        int x = placeholder1.Location.X;
        int y = placeholder1.Location.Y;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 64;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 64;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 64;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 64;

        placeholder1.Location = new Point(x, y);

        movesLeft--;

        Console.WriteLine($"{movesLeft} moves left!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you press the key down you start from 6 moves. Try this if you want to use all 6 moves in 1 press (please note: you can avoid using a loop here):

```
int spaceMoved = 6;    
private void Gameplay_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    do
    {
        int x = placeholder1.Location.X;
        int y = placeholder1.Location.Y;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 64;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 64;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 64;
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 64;

        placeholder1.Location = new Point(x, y);

        spaceMoved--;

        Console.WriteLine(spaceMoved);

    } while (spaceMoved > 0);
}
```

Or if you don't want to use all 6 at once, but only 1 per key press (not very clear from your question), do this:

```
int spaceMoved = 6;    
private void Gameplay_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{  
    int x = placeholder1.Location.X;
    int y = placeholder1.Location.Y;

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right) x += 64;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) x -= 64;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) y += 64;
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up) y -= 64;

    placeholder1.Location = new Point(x, y);

    spaceMoved--;

    Console.WriteLine(spaceMoved);
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't look like what they want. They want the player to be able to move six times in total. This uses up all six move in one keypress.

Comment: Well he shouldn't use 'do-while' loop then. But I don't think that's what he is saying. Anyway, edited my post to include both cases

Comment: @TeodorNarliyski: It's obviously not uncommon for a problem to contain a mistake somewhere, as is the case with the `do while` here. Context is key, and the context suggests repeating the same move 6 times is not what the OP wants. Also, it doesn't make sense to use a `do while` _even if_ the intention is to perform 6 moves (as you could simply in/decrement by `64*6` once).

Comment: @Flater I agree, I guess you are right and he wants to do what I put in my second solution because as you said the first one has lots of code that can be optimized (aka no need of loop).

Answer (score -2):

Your do wile condition is still valid that's why it's running over and over. Try to make with for loop it'll be fine

int spacemoved = 6;

```
for(int i = 0; i<= spacemoved; i++)
{
 do something();
}
```

Comment: Now *that's* an infinite loop - assuming it compiles. If you pull `spacemoved` outside the block, `spacemoved` will always be less than 7

Comment: Not only does this answer not answer the question, it creates a problem where previously there was none.

Comment: i think this answer can help him solve this problem. @Flater

Comment: @AboubacarTraore: The answer (even after editing) clearly proves you're not seeing what is effectively an obvious infinite loop. This answer creates the issue that the question asks to solve.

Comment: He said that he created an infinit loop that he did not want too !!